# Laravel 8 on sub-domain

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-8, cpanel

I have been searching, searching and searching with no success.
I'm very new to Laravel and the learning curve is pretty steep to build a simple 4 page web site !! :)

I have set-up a sub-domain using cpanel and the proper document root for the sub-domain.
I have copied the complete Laravel 8 project to the sub-domain document root.
When I access the sub-domain, I'm getting the Laravel 404 page.
I have changed the index.php to Hello and it get's served. So the sub-domain is properly set-up.

sub-domain: xyz.website.com
Document root: /xyz/public where public is the public folder inside of a Laravel project.

**First Question**
How do I turn on logging to get more details as to what is happening !!
I have ensured that the .env file has the following:

`APP_DEBUG=true and APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug`

I cannot see any logging happening. I've looked in the **storage/logs** folder and it is empty.

**Second Question**
I have seen many posts stating that the .htaccess needs to be changed.
Not sure that this is applicable for sub-domains with the proper document root configured.

As you can see, I'm in dire need of some help and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Laravel is meant to be run so the `/public` directory points at the web root. Make sure you configure this properly when you set up the domain in cpanel. Also make sure the `.htaccess` file is set up. Note this is a special file for Apache. That is its exact name. Note it begins with a dot. It doesn't use a file extension like .txt or anything of the such. Within cpanel, there's an option to show hidden files so you'll need to check that before browsing around in order to see it.

Comment: Also note for laravel you'll want CLI access so you can do things like running `composer install` etc. Or at least doing that locally then deploying to your production server such as through git and git pulling etc assuming you have SSH access.

Comment: You should post this on [sf] as here we help with code, not setting up a server.

Comment: @KevinY Can you kindly point direct me to any reference explaining what is needed in the .htaccess for Laravel 8?

Comment: There's many resources for this. Probably the majority of the resources you find will give you a solution that will work for `.htaccess` just look around for what you need.  There's many .htaccess setups that will work for laravel which are all very similar. Laravel includes its own .htaccess file. You can find it here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/8.x/public